# "Only SELECT queries allowed" error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning sql. I took few courses, so I'm starting to train with real database in real situation. I'm using Supermetrics to query a wordpress mysql database. I wrote the following request :

```
Select wp_users.user_nicename,
wp_users.display_name,wp_10_posts.post_title,wp_10_posts.post_author,wp_10_posts.post_date
from wp_10_posts
Inner join wp_users
on wp_10_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_10_posts.post_date DESC;
limit 150
```

And I have the following error : `"Only SELECT queries allowed"`

Comment: limit should be within the query (ie before the semi-colon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong `;`   position.   The `;` must be at the end of the query otherwise the LIMIT 150 is used as a new sql command

```
  Select 
      wp_users.user_nicename
      ,wp_users.display_name
      ,wp_10_posts.post_title
      ,wp_10_posts.post_author
      ,wp_10_posts.post_date
  from wp_10_posts
  Inner join wp_users on wp_10_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID
  ORDER BY wp_10_posts.post_date DESC 
  limit 150;
```

Comment: I didn't DV you, but maybe because the question was just about a typo, and as low quality question someone thought it didn't merit an a full blown answer, but just a comment (and further deletion).

Comment: Good on you. IMO we don't need more of this, but less.

Comment: @yivi I respect your opinion, even if not fully agree (for OP novice I believe that the code is better than Comment) and especially really appreciate the fact that we speak openly and express different opinions .. this is very useful and construction .. I do not like those who vote negatively on the sly

Comment: Again, didn't DV you. Voted to close the question though. But you shouldn't take DV badly. Votes are **exactly** to express opinions, is not personal. And the idea is not helping the OP, but creating a better site. And a site filled with duplicates and answers about typos helps no one.

Comment: @Yivi, helping the OP is the main purpose of answering questions. Otherwise we might as well be a blog only. It may look like a typo to you, but it is a missed understanding as well or he woudl have seen the typo. That is why the person answering this explained more than just fixed teh typo.

Comment: @HLGEM, I think you are wrong. The site's mission is not to help a particular user, but to create a repository of organized knowledge. That's exactly the reason why we have a close reason which states: "typo or no longer reproducible". This is not a forum or a help-desk. The idea is not to have another user come along in five minutes having put a semi-colon wrongly in another query, and having to answer that **again**. Asnwering this kind of question is what's known as "polishing a turd". :) But this is more fit to [meta] than here. Bowing out. Peace!

Comment: @yivi, Frankly I would rather help someone than be a site purist. The OP had a misconception about what the purpose of the ; was and the person writing the answer showed why ti was wrong not just fixing it. Now that person will understand the next time what to look for. Beginners have a different level of problem than advanced users and this site is not just for advanced people. Closing all beginners questions and calling them turds (how insulting BTW) drives people away who actually need help.

Comment: I'm not calling the user a turd, nor would ever. Voting is never about the user, but about the post content. The turd is the question (because it is poorly tested and researched, only helps the OP **and no one else**), and the act of polishing because you are doing more to PRESERVE it, hence adding noise to the site. Is not about being a purist. Is about helping the most people. A question that only helps one user is a bad question. Adds noise and makes harder to actually find useful content.

Answer (score 3):

should work now! Moved the semicolon to the end of the query....

```
Select wp_users.user_nicename,
wp_users.display_name,wp_10_posts.post_title,wp_10_posts.post_author,wp_10_posts.post_date
from wp_10_posts
Inner join wp_users
on wp_10_posts.post_author=wp_users.ID
ORDER BY wp_10_posts.post_date DESC
limit 150;
```

Comment: What did you change? What was wrong? Code only answers aren't useful for the site, try to expand a bit and explain your answer.

Comment: changed the position of semicolon to the end of the query

Comment: put it in your answer.